# Setting visible property on .NET controls

Tags: asp.net, dynamic

.NET newbie here.

I have a page with a number of sections to it.  I want to create another page to have hyperlinks to this page, and hyperlinks to the sections within it.

I want all the sections to be visible if the user has clicked on the main page link, but only the section that the user has asked for if (s)he has clicked on the section hyperlinks.

How do i set the visible property of the non-requested controls (in asp:Panel's) from the link on the previous page, so they don't appear on the page when a different section is requested?

many tia

mcalex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following options

1. Wrap each section controls inside an asp.net panel server control
2. When you click the hyperlink on the main page, pass the panel to enable via querystring or session as a parameter like on your linkbuton

   ```
   Response.Redirect("~/myPage.aspx?secId=info")
   ```
3. Then on your redirected page set all panels `Visibility=false` inside pageLoad check for querstring value & set the panel's visible property to true or false

   ```
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         string panelToEnable= Request.QueryString["secId"];
         switch(panelToEnable)
         {
             case("info"):
                        panelInfo.Visible=true; 
                        break;
             case("details");
                        panelDetails.Visible=true;
                        break;
             default:
                        panelMaster.Visible=true; 
                        break;
         }
    }
   ```

Alternatively you can place the section links inside the redirected page & further simplify things (remove querystring etc.)

Comment: This approach makes sense, but I'm not much of a web person (lol, i'm from java).  How do i get access to the Response if my main page link is an asp:Hyperlink?  The hyperlink tag doesn't seem to have a Request or Response property.
mcalex

Comment: You can either use a server side linkbutton control & double click on it to write Response.Redirect or you can just hard code on your a tag like <a href="myPage.aspx?secId=info">Info Section</a>

Comment: @mcalex glad it helped you. If you find my post useful you can upvote also please mark it as answer if you got solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]`

However, if the user refreshes the page, this will change.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to do this issue:

1. Use query string: pass your different parameter values on the query string. In the destination page/control, check the query string and make the section visible/invisible as your requirement
2. Use session data: use a specific key for storing the mode. When you click on the link button of other pages, use the call back function (in CSharp) to set the session data and redirect to the destination page. This page will check the data that stored in session state and make the section visible/invisible.

Pros & Cons:

- The 1st solution can be used for pure HTML link but the parameter is shown in query string so user can change it to display the other sections.
- The 2nd solution can not be used for pure HTML link but it prevents user changing the values in session state. So it is more security.